# Not able to consume my second web method in same web service

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services

In continuation to my previous question [Not able to consume my web service through jQuery / AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54515246/not-able-to-consume-my-web-service-through-jquery-ajax) i'm facing the problem again. I have now two `[WebMethod]` in my web service file. First one is `FormSubmit()` which works fine now and second one is `LoginOnClick`  This is my code:

```
[WebMethod]
        public void LoginOnClick(agentLoginInfo agentLoginObject)
        {
            string agentID = "";
            string agentPassword = "";
            try
            {
                if (agentLoginObject != null)
                {
                    agentID = agentLoginObject.agentID;
                    agentPassword = agentLoginObject.agentPassword;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("No Data");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write("Error :" + e.Message);
            }
            RequestBLObject.AgentID = agentLoginObject.agentID.Trim();
            RequestBLObject.AgentPassword = agentLoginObject.agentPassword.Trim();
            DataTable UserDetails = new DataTable();

            UserDetails = BehaviourBLObject.ValidateUsernamePasswordBL(RequestBLObject);


        }
```

This is the AJAX:

```
function Login() {
            var agentLoginObject = {};
            var ID = $("#AgentID").val();
            var Password = $("#Password").val();
            agentLoginObject.AgentID = ID;
            agentLoginObject.AgentPassword = Password;
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://arohar.com/Service.asmx/LoginOnClick',
                data: "{agentLoginObject:" + JSON.stringify(agentLoginObject) + "}",
                processData: false,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function() {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        }
```

Keeping in mind what mistakes i did last time, i tried my best but i ran into same problem again. Can anyone point out where i went wrong again this time?

UPDATE:  I saw on my networks tab and this is what I get every time

```
System.InvalidOperationException: LoginOnClick Web Service method name is not valid.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

Comment: Try to use: data: JSON.stringify(agentLoginObject)

Comment: @EltonGarciadeSantana you mean i should remove ` "{agentLoginObject:"` from data?

Comment: yes, I believe your object is already on the required format

Comment: i tried but no luck. shall i post the error that i saw on network's tab?

Comment: Yes, that might be useful

Comment: I've updated my question with error. Please check